# opencart2 is there any directory select field

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I want to add a field to my custom module in which I want to be able to select a directory inside an images directory.

Are there any tools like select image which is the bultin tool for open cart but with the ability to select directory instead of single image?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution

using Vqmod its possible to customize filemanager to add a button to folders so its possible to select a directory

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo $entry_images_url; ?></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10"><a href="" id="thumb-images_url" data-toggle="image" class="img-thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="" title="" data-placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" /></a>
                    <input type="text" name="images_url" value="<?php echo $images_url; ?>" id="input-images_url" />
                </div>              
            </div>
```

Note that I used

> type="text"

instead of hidden input.

Then i create a vqmod xml file like this to customize the filemanager common core file:
https://github.com/mhd-jalilvand/oc-vqmod-filemanager-select_dir

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this:

```
image/some_folder
```

instead of this:

```
image/some_folder/img.jpg
```

I know there must be better solution, but you can use javaScript `split()` method , create an `array` based on `/`, and then remove last `index` of `array`.

Comment: thank you but I want to know if there is a utility in the opencart core to select a directory